# Excel Vba Macro to Do several Things in Order

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get 1 macro to be generalized so it will work on multiple reports. The problem is it may not always have everything ie: one will have a header one will not, one will have a column "this one" one will not, one will have 5 sheets or varying names one will have 13..

I want to do the following:
  1. always keep all rows and columns auto sized
  2. always freeze the first row
  3. always delete the header row (if there is one)
  4. always change the tabs to a pattern (red, blue, green, yellow, orange repeat for every sheet)
  5. hide a list of columns by column name (this one, that one, another one no matter where in the report they are)
  6. make sure that the frozen top row is filterable (like pressing ctrl shift l)

I think this is on the right track but its not doing it the best it can, any suggestions to make it error proof (like not to fail if it doesnt have the right # of tabs or the column names) and a better way call all of the individual macros one after another.

Thanks!!

```
Sub Auto_Size_Columns()
' Autosize the column after filling it all in.
Columns("A:CO").Select
Columns("A:CO").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("A1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Call Freeze_Top_Panes
End Sub

Sub Freeze_Top_Panes()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Rows("2:2").Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Call Auto_Size_Columns_Again
End Sub

Sub Auto_Size_Columns_Again()
' Autosize the column after filling it all in.

Columns("A:CO").Select
Columns("A:CO").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("A1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Call Delete_Header_Row
End Sub

Sub Delete_Header_Row()
'delete the extra header row
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.Delete shift:=xlUp
Range("A1").Select
Call Tab_Color_Change
End Sub

Sub Tab_Color_Change()
Sheets("Sheet2").Tab.ColorIndex = 3
Sheets("Sheet3").Tab.ColorIndex = 4
Sheets("Sheet4").Tab.ColorIndex = 5
Sheets("Sheet5").Tab.ColorIndex = 6
Sheets("Sheet6").Tab.ColorIndex = 7
Sheets("Sheet7").Tab.ColorIndex = 8
Sheets("Sheet8").Tab.ColorIndex = 9
Sheets("Sheet9").Tab.ColorIndex = 10
Sheets("Sheet10").Tab.ColorIndex = 11
Sheets("Sheet11").Tab.ColorIndex = 12
Sheets("Sheet12").Tab.ColorIndex = 13
Sheets("Sheet13").Tab.ColorIndex = 14
Call Hide_Columns
End Sub

Sub Hide_Columns()
Dim s As Worksheet, N As Long, i As Long
For Each s In Worksheets
    s.Activate
    N = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For i = 1 To N
        If Left(Cells(1, i).Value, 6) = "this one" Then
            Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next i
Next s
Call Auto_Size_Columns_Last
End Sub

Sub Auto_Size_Columns_Last()
' Autosize the column after filling it all in.

Columns("A:CO").Select
Columns("A:CO").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("A1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
End Sub
```

Comment: If my answer provides a sufficient solution to the problem, please mark it as answered, otherwise provide further clarification in your question

Answer (score 2):

I think to start off first you'll want to look into how to loop through all the pages in your current workbook.

```
Sub DoSheetActions()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim CurrentColorIndex As Integer
    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
        'Execute commands for each sheet
        'To do this, you'll need to pass the each sheet to the Subroutine.
        Auto_Size_Columns ws

        'Increase the ColorIndex each time we iterate over a new sheet
        CurrentColorIndex = CurrentColorIndex + 1
        'Retrieve a new ColorIndex
        ws.Tab.ColorIndex = Tab_Color_Change(CurrentColorIndex)
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Now that we are looping through each sheet, we can call any number of actions on each sheet one by one.  Auto_Size_Columns is pretty simple.

```
Sub Auto_Size_Columns(ws As Worksheet)
    'And to be honest, Auto_Size_Columns() probably 
    'doesn't need to be a Sub as it only has one statement.
    'Using Worksheet.UsedRange we can find
    'all the columns (as long as there isn't a gap)
    ws.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Next, we can address setting the sheet's color index for N number of sheets in the workbook by using a Function to determine which color to use based on how many sheet's we've iterated over (CurrentColorIndex).

```
'Passing ColorIndex byref so this function can change the value
'You could also use a Switch to get a more robust method to
'determine which color index to return
Function Tab_Color_Change(ByRef ColorIndex As Integer) As Integer
    'So if the value is less than 3, it starts off as 3.
    If (ColorIndex < 3) Then
        ColorIndex = 3
    'If the value is greater than 14, start back at 3.
    ElseIf (ColorIndex > 14) Then
        ColorIndex = 3
    End If

    'Return the color
    Tab_Color_Change = ColorIndex
End Function
```

The only thing I did not cover was removing headers if they exist. But in essence, to determine whether or not a header exists, you'll need a common header column that exists in all sheets, and if it exists you can safely remove Row 1.  Otherwise you'll wind up deleting your data.

I hope this gives you a different way to look at things and a starting point for your future endeavors. Cheers.